# Javascript - Bypass new element in script

Tags: javascript, spry

I have a group of tabs that change the main panel when clicked on. In order to change a particular color property, I need to insert an additional div into my HTML. However, when I do so, it cause an error in the javascript. I'm not a javascript expert, but I think the reason is that the script is calling for an element in a particular order. So when I throw a new element into the picture, it loses its track. Here's my HTML. Basically all the items in the ul are always visible, and when you click on one, it makes the corresponding content visible:

```
<div id="TabbedPanels">
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="VTabbedPanels">
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
     <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">1</div>
     <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">2</div>
     <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">3</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">2</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

So now I want to slip a div around theTabbedPanelsContentGroup div, but like I said, it messes everything up. Here's the complete js:

```
var Spry;
if (!Spry) Spry = {};
if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels = function(element, opts)
{
    this.element = this.getElement(element);
    this.defaultTab = 0; // Show the first panel by default.
    this.tabSelectedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
    this.tabHoverClass = "TabbedPanelsTabHover";
    this.tabFocusedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabFocused";
    this.panelVisibleClass = "TabbedPanelsContentVisible";
    this.focusElement = null;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.currentTabIndex = 0;
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
    this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT;
    this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT;

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions(this, opts);

    // If the defaultTab is expressed as a number/index, convert
    // it to an element.

    if (typeof (this.defaultTab) == "number")
    {
        if (this.defaultTab < 0)
            this.defaultTab = 0;
        else
        {
            var count = this.getTabbedPanelCount();
            if (this.defaultTab >= count)
                this.defaultTab = (count > 1) ? (count - 1) : 0;
        }

        this.defaultTab = this.getTabs()[this.defaultTab];
    }

    // The defaultTab property is supposed to be the tab element for the tab content
    // to show by default. The caller is allowed to pass in the element itself or the
    // element's id, so we need to convert the current value to an element if necessary.

    if (this.defaultTab)
        this.defaultTab = this.getElement(this.defaultTab);

    this.attachBehaviors();
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElementChildren = function(element)
{
    var children = [];
    var child = element.firstChild;
    while (child)
    {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 /* Node.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            children.push(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return children;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) != -1))
        return;
    ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.removeClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1))
        return;
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions = function(obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps)
{
    if (!optionsObj)
        return;
    for (var optionName in optionsObj)
    {
        if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined)
            continue;
        obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
    }
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabGroup = function()
{
    if (this.element)
    {
        var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
        if (children.length)
            return children[1];
    }
    return null;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabs = function()
{
    var tabs = [];
    var tg = this.getTabGroup();
    if (tg)
        tabs = this.getElementChildren(tg);
    return tabs;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanelGroup = function()
{
    if (this.element)
    {
        var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
        if (children.length > 1)
            return children[0];
    }
    return null;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanels = function()
{
    var panels = [];
    var pg = this.getContentPanelGroup();
    if (pg)
        panels = this.getElementChildren(pg);
    return panels;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getIndex = function(ele, arr)
{
    ele = this.getElement(ele);
    if (ele && arr && arr.length)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (ele == arr[i])
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabIndex = function(ele)
{
    var i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getTabs());
    if (i < 0)
        i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getContentPanels());
    return i;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getCurrentTabIndex = function()
{
    return this.currentTabIndex;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabbedPanelCount = function(ele)
{
    return Math.min(this.getTabs().length, this.getContentPanels().length);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener = function(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    try
    {
        if (element.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
        else if (element.attachEvent)
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
    }
    catch (e) {}
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.cancelEvent = function(e)
{
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    else e.returnValue = false;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;

    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabClick = function(e, tab)
{
    this.showPanel(tab);
    return this.cancelEvent(e);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOver = function(e, tab)
{
    this.addClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOut = function(e, tab)
{
    this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabFocus = function(e, tab)
{
    this.hasFocus = true;
    this.addClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabBlur = function(e, tab)
{
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_UP = 38;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_DOWN = 40;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT = 37;
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT = 39;



Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabKeyDown = function(e, tab)
{
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!this.hasFocus || (key != this.previousPanelKeyCode && key != this.nextPanelKeyCode))
        return true;

    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    for (var i =0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        if (tabs[i] == tab)
        {
            var el = false;
            if (key == this.previousPanelKeyCode && i > 0)
                el = tabs[i-1];
            else if (key == this.nextPanelKeyCode && i < tabs.length-1)
                el = tabs[i+1];

            if (el)
            {
                this.showPanel(el);
                el.focus();
                break;
            }
        }

    return this.cancelEvent(e);
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.preorderTraversal = function(root, func)
{
    var stopTraversal = false;
    if (root)
    {
        stopTraversal = func(root);
        if (root.hasChildNodes())
        {
            var child = root.firstChild;
            while (!stopTraversal && child)
            {
                stopTraversal = this.preorderTraversal(child, func);
                try { child = child.nextSibling; } catch (e) { child = null; }
            }
        }
    }
    return stopTraversal;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addPanelEventListeners = function(tab, panel)
{
    var self = this;
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "click", function(e) { return self.onTabClick(e, tab); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseover", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOver(e, tab); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseout", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOut(e, tab); }, false);

    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
    {
        // XXX: IE doesn't allow the setting of tabindex dynamically. This means we can't
        // rely on adding the tabindex attribute if it is missing to enable keyboard navigation
        // by default.

        // Find the first element within the tab container that has a tabindex or the first
        // anchor tag.

        var tabIndexEle = null;
        var tabAnchorEle = null;

        this.preorderTraversal(tab, function(node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 1 /* NODE.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            {
                var tabIndexAttr = tab.attributes.getNamedItem("tabindex");
                if (tabIndexAttr)
                {
                    tabIndexEle = node;
                    return true;
                }
                if (!tabAnchorEle && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a")
                    tabAnchorEle = node;
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (tabIndexEle)
            this.focusElement = tabIndexEle;
        else if (tabAnchorEle)
            this.focusElement = tabAnchorEle;

        if (this.focusElement)
        {
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "focus", function(e) { return self.onTabFocus(e, tab); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "blur", function(e) { return self.onTabBlur(e, tab); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "keydown", function(e) { return self.onTabKeyDown(e, tab); }, false);
        }
    }
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.showPanel = function(elementOrIndex)
{
    var tpIndex = -1;

    if (typeof elementOrIndex == "number")
        tpIndex = elementOrIndex;
    else // Must be the element for the tab or content panel.
        tpIndex = this.getTabIndex(elementOrIndex);

    if (!tpIndex < 0 || tpIndex >= this.getTabbedPanelCount())
        return;

    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    var panels = this.getContentPanels();

    var numTabbedPanels = Math.max(tabs.length, panels.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < numTabbedPanels; i++)
    {
        if (i != tpIndex)
        {
            if (tabs[i])
                this.removeClassName(tabs[i], this.tabSelectedClass);
            if (panels[i])
            {
                this.removeClassName(panels[i], this.panelVisibleClass);
                panels[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    this.addClassName(tabs[tpIndex], this.tabSelectedClass);
    this.addClassName(panels[tpIndex], this.panelVisibleClass);
    panels[tpIndex].style.display = "block";

    this.currentTabIndex = tpIndex;
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.attachBehaviors = function(element)
{
    var tabs = this.getTabs();
    var panels = this.getContentPanels();
    var panelCount = this.getTabbedPanelCount();

    for (var i = 0; i < panelCount; i++)
        this.addPanelEventListeners(tabs[i], panels[i]);

    this.showPanel(this.defaultTab);
};
```

I think it could work if I could just figure out where in the js to bypass the new element I'm inserting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any other JavaScript that makes use of Spry and sets up the tabbed panels? This might occur in your HTML page inside <script> tags.

Comment: Yeah, TNi. This sets it up:

<script type="text/javascript">
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1", { interval: 6000 });
TabbedPanels1.start();
</script>

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to achieve styling, like changing some color without the need to resort to additional divs. Just add a class to the top div and change your css accordingly
2. If you currently initialize with `Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels('TabbedPanels')`, changing it to `Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels('TabbedPanels1')` should do the trick.. (*if i understand your problem and edits correctly*)

Comment: The problem is the container already has a background color and a border. But I'm trying to achieve a background color, some colored padding, and a border.

Comment: I'm sorry, everyone, but this was just a workaround for this other problem I was having:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220439/combining-multiple-javascript-fade-effects

But I think I can get that problem solved by using absolute positioning. So please ignore this question unless it's helpful to anyone else. And I could still use some help on the other one.

Thanks.

Comment: @Beau, I see, I assume that you added the `<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="VTabbedPanels">` part, correct? if so, have you tried the second part in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to put additional styles on each `TabbedPanelsContent` element. You can add the same children `<div>` for styling in each tab. For another solution, I have not tested this, but a change like the following might work:

```
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanelGroup = function()
{
    if (this.element)
    {
        var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
        if (children.length > 1)
        {
            var subchildren = this.getElementChildren(children[0]);
            return subchildren[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```